# Find character in file name bash

Tags: bash

I have a bunch of files whose names are in the format:

```
artist name - song name.mp3
```

I am writing a bash script that will extract the artist and song name and put the file in a directory named "artist name" and the filename would just be "song name.mp3".

How would I find the "-" so I can parse the artist and song name to their appropriate variables. Also, how would I check to see if a certain "artist name" already has a directory and then put that new file into that directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that this does what you want:

```
for f in *.mp3; do artist=${f%% - *}; song=${f#* - }; mkdir -p "$artist"; mv "$f" "$artist/$song"; done
```

Or, if you were to write in a script:

```
for f in *.mp3; do 
    artist=${f%% - *}
    song=${f#* - }
    mkdir -p "$artist"
    mv "$f" "$artist/$song"
done
```

#### How it works

- `for f in *.mp3; do`

  This starts a loop over every mp3 file in the current directory.
- `artist=${f%% - *}; song=${f#* - }`

  This extracts the artist's name and saves it in the shell variable `artist` and extracts the song's name and saves it in the shell variable `song`.

  This uses the three characters space-dash-space as the divider between artists and song.

  `${f%% - *}` is an example of *suffix removal*.  The shell looks for the longest pattern (glob) of `- *` and removes it from the end of the variable `f`.

  `${f#* - }` is an example of *prefix removal*.  The shell looks for the shortest pattern (glob) for `* -` and removes it from the beginning of the variable `f`.

  Both suffix removal and prefix removal are documented in `man bash` under the heading "Parameter Expansion".
- `mkdir -p "$artist"`

  This makes sure that there is a directory named for the artist.
- `mv "$f" "$artist/$song"`

  This moves the mp3 file to the directory
- `done`

  This signals the end of the loop.

Comment: The last `$artist` should be `$song`

Comment: Can you provide a link to documentation of the `${...}` patterns?

Comment: @user3439894 and das-g, that is all documented in `man bash`.  I have updated the answer with some discussion of the two.

Comment: @John1024, I just did a quick search `man bash` and skimmed the relevant portions, thanks I now have a much better understanding how to use it. +1 :)